# The principle of LM deep model

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, language-model, transformer

Language model(LM) is the task of predicting the next word.

Does the deep model need the encoder? From the ptb code of tensor2tensor, I find the deep model do not contains the encoder.

Or both with-encoder and without-encoder can do the LM task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal of LM is to learn a probability distribution over sequences
>   of symbols pertaining to a language.

That is, to learn $P(w_1,...,w_N)$ ([resource](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02410)).

This modeling can be accomplished by

1. Predicting the next word given the previous words: $P(w_i | w_1,...,w_{i-1})$, or
2. Predicting the neighbor words given the center word ([Skip-gram](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4546)): $P(w_{i+k}| w_i), k \in \{-2, -1, 1, 2\}$, or
3. Predicting the center word given the neighbor words ([CBOW](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) or Continuous Bag-of-Words): $P(w_i| w_{i-2},w_{i-1},w_{i+1}, w_{i+2})$, or other designs.

> Does the deep model need the encoder? From the ptb code of
>   tensor2tensor, I find the deep model do not contains the encoder.

Yes. Modern LM solutions (all *deep* ones) try to find an encoding (embedding) that helps them to predict the next, neighbor, or center words as close as possible. However, a word encoding can be used as a **constant** input to other models. The [ptb.py code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/data_generators/ptb.py) calls `text_encoder.TokenTextEncoder` to receive such word encodings.

> Both with-encoder and without-encoder can do the LM task?

LM task can be tackled without encoders too. For example, we can use frequency tables of adjacent words to build a model ([n-gram modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-gram_models)); e.g. all pairs (We, ?) appeared 10K times, pair (We, can) appeared 100 times, so P(can | We) = 0.01. However, encoder is the core of modern LM solutions.